# C# / .NET Core way to filter out non-Roman characters but allow all accents and diacritics of Roman letters in all languages that use them

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm looking for an efficient way to validate a website textbox and textarea input elements.  The input is for **human readable text only**, like name, address, comments, question, survey answer, etc.  In addition the valid input should only allow for all variety of Roman/Latin characters, including those included in Latin1, Latin2, Latin3, and Latin4 character sets (see [wikipedia of ISO-8859 parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859)).  This is because our call center can only read Roman characters (no Chinese, Korean, Japanese, Thai, Russian, Arabic, Hebrew, Greek, etc.), because at least when the language is not English, they can use Google translate, or when the text input is used for address, it can still make sense on the address label or invoice.

Since it is web input, the UTF-8 characters transmitted via HTTP are converted by the C# system into Unicode (UTF-16) internally.  I want a function returning a boolean that can say whether there is a non-Roman/Latin character in the string, but it should not be too stringent to disallow uncommon accented roman letter such as the French Œ, the German ẞ, the Irish Ṡ, the Finnish Ž, the Danish Ǿ, etc. (all those are not in Latin1, not to mention ASCII).  Of course all punctuation marks should trigger a false; this should take care of HTML/JS/SQL injection issue.  A second validator (not part of this question) will filter allowable punctuation mark like hyphen, period, apostrophe, etc.

**I'm looking for ideas, not necessarily code**.  I have a feeling that there is a NuGet package out there or an already made function that uses .NET facility like [System.Char.IsLetter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter?view=netcore-2.2) and [System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=netcore-2.2#System_Globalization_UnicodeCategory_UppercaseLetter).

The value of this question comes from other developers requiring the same kind of validation.  Partial answers are welcome, and I will post the final solution on this question for everyone to use.  (Let's see whether this question edit can redeem the current -2 vote for this question :-) )

**EDIT:**

Responding to negative comments below, I realize "non-Roman" is a little vague for computer geeks who like precision.  But we are in the age of cloud where all people speaking all kinds of language are entering stuff into a web page.  I want to restrict the input to all varieties of Roman / Latin characters.  By "Roman" I mean anything derived from a,b,c,d,e,...x,y,z.  Pretty common sense, don't you think?  So I want to allow characters similar to those letters used by speakers of French, German, Danish, Norwegian, Bulgarians, etc. BUT excluding  Chinese, Korean, Japanese, Thai, Russian, Arabic, Hebrew, Greek characters.  Nothing wrong with them, but it's simply a business policy so the characters in the database are at least readable and sortable.

So I'm not looking for anything super precise here, and a basic guideline is that it needs to include all letters defined in Latin1, Latin2, Latin3, and Latin4 character sets, but I require the filter to detect them as unicode (so has numerical value of a unicode character, not Latin3 character set).  I think the criteria is specific enough.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.  Also include what you have tried and any code related to the issue(s).

Comment: What's wrong with non-Roman characters? It would really help if you explained [what problem you're trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/135230), not just what solution you have decided to use.

Comment: Maybe `char.IsLetter()` and `char.IsDigit()` are what you're looking for. `IsLetter` is pretty broad about what it accepts.

Comment: @DourHighArch  nothing wrong with non-Roman.  I edited the question to clarify purpose and criteria.

Comment: @ScottHannen Thank you.  You pointed me in the right direction.  I just now need to find out how to exclude Hebrew, Arabic, and other non-Roman characters.  UnicodeCategory Enum looks promising.

Comment: I don't mean to sound facetious, but just asking this question makes me smile. Once punctuation and other non-letter symbols are eliminated, how can Hebrew and Arabic possibly be malicious? What does a malicious Arabic character injection look like? سأنزل مكدس الفائض

Comment: @ScottHannen Pardon not to wear cultural sensitivity hat, political sensitivity hat, etc.  I meant nothing of the sort.  I assumed I am in the company of programmers, who already know that by "malicious" I meant HTML tags, JS script, SQL injection, etc.  I'm in no way implying non-roman alphabets are malicious; that portion is business requirement so the call center people are not at a loss in communicating to the customer.  So I I'm going to edit my question again to prevent misunderstanding.

Comment: @TonyAbrams I have extensively edited the question.  Please let me know if it meets the standard now.

Comment: @PaulS.Lee won't `Char.GetUnicodeCategory` suffice that or what pitfalls you found within it?

Comment: @PaulS.Lee - my sincerest apologies. That detail of the question triggered my odd sense of humor. I didn't mean to imply anything along those lines, or that there was some significance to which character sets you wanted to exclude. I don't think anyone thought that. (edit: darn, I said "trigger.")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reviewing tips from Sten, Scott Hannen and Prix, I decided to go with the following:

```cs
        private static string AllowedCharacterRegexPattern = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\+,\-\.'/@_#& ]|[\u00C0-\u024F]|[\u1E00-\u1EFF])+$";
        public static bool AllowedCharacter(string s)
        {
            // Decision:  Characters to include:
            //     Basic Latin: 0x0030-0039, 0x0041-0x005A, 0x0061-0x007A:  0-9, A-Z, a-z  :  (https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf)
            //     Latin1: 0x00C0 - 0x00FF (https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf)
            //     Latin Extended A: 0x0100-0x017F (https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf)
            //     Latin Extended-B: 0x0180-0x24F (https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0180.pdf)
            //     Latin Extended Additional: 0x1E00-0x1EFF (https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1E00.pdf)
            //     Some punctuation: ( ) + , - . ' / @ _ # &
            return Regex.IsMatch(s, AllowedCharacterRegexPattern);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using regular expressions, which support [named Unicode blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks).

Your regex may look something like

`(\s|\p{IsBasicLatin}|\p{IsCombiningDiacriticalMarks})+`

You could also have a broader range with exclusions. For example:

`[\u0000-\u036F-[\p{P}\p{IsIPAExtensions}]]`

Of course, you'd need to test and tweak the exact regex to allow/disallow punctuation and other character classes.

Comment: Thank you for the assist.  I accepted your answer, and provided my solution as promised in another answer below.